# Loop through files in a directory for a particular file. If the file is not there, append a "File not found" to a list else append the file location

Tags: python-3.x, file, file-not-found

I have a list of file names in an excel sheet that I need the file location to. I want the code to run through all the files in the directory specified and if it finds the file, to append the file location to a list. If it doesn't find the file, I want it to append a "File not found" to the list.

I've got my code to work if the file does exist, however, I can't seem to find a way to solve the problem when the file doesn't exist. I've tried:

```
if name not in file:
   file_location.append("File Not Found")
```

but what this does is append a "File Not Found" for each file it loops through.

```
def file_loc(basedir, filename):
    """Searches through the directory for a particular file and then saves that path into a list"""
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(basedir):
        for name in files:
            if filename in name:
                location = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(root, name))
                file_location.append(location)
```

I would like a list that prints out all the file locations of the files in a list and if a file location cannot be found, the list should contain a "File Not Found". So for example, if the files I wanted to search for were `[foo, bar, soap]` and the soap file was not in my directory it would print out:

```
[File/path/to/foo, File/path/to/bar, "File Not Found"]
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you are checking whether a particular file name matches, and you want to know if any matched. If after you have run through all the files none matched, then you can say it was not found. So I would suggest using a boolean variable to see if it was found at all. Then after the loop is complete check and append if necessary. It should look something like this.

```
def file_loc(basedir, filename):
"""Searches through the directory for a particular file and then saves that path into a list"""
found = false
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(basedir):
    for name in files:
        if filename in name:
            location = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(root, name))
            file_location.append(location)
            found = True
if not found:
  file_location.append("File Not Found")
```

Comment: by the way, I answered what was asked, but I would imagine if a file shows up multiple times or just anyway it will be annoying to track what file was not found. consider "File Not Found: " + filename.

Comment: Absolute Legend! Worked great, never thought about using a boolean for this case. Once again, thanks!